# Using Public Arrays in Different Classes

Tags: java, arrays

I am a beginning Java user and I am experiencing errors when using two public arrays in a different class. The program is supposed to model 3 interstellar bodies through mathematical integration. Note: I am new to this website and haven't been able to figure the formatting yet.

```
package gravitationalmodel;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GravitationalModel 
{
  private Object timer;
  private GravitationalObject G1;
  private GravitationalObject G2;
  private GravitationalObject G3;
  public static double[] xArray;
  public static double[] yArray;
  final public double gravConst = 0.000000000067; 
  final public int refreshRate = 25;


  public GravitationalModel()
  {
    Timer timer = new Timer(refreshRate, (ActionListener) this); // refreshes model every 25 milliseconds
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    GravitationalObject G1 = new GravitationalObject(500, 500, 10, 10, 10); // creates 3 interstellar objects taking x position,
    GravitationalObject G2 = new GravitationalObject(400, 400, 10, 10, 10); // y position, x veleocity component, y velocity component
    GravitationalObject G3 = new GravitationalObject(600, 600, 10, 10, 10); // mass of the object


    xArray = new double[1920]; // assigns all elements of array to 0
    for (int x = 0; x < 1920; ++x)
    {
        xArray[x] = 0;
        //System.out.println(xArray[x]);
    }


    yArray = new double[1200];
    for (int x = 0; x < 1200; ++x)
    {
        yArray[x] = 0;
        //System.out.println(yArray[x]);
    }
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) // refreshes model
  {
    G1.refreshVectorField();
    G2.refreshVectorField();
    G3.refreshVectorField();
    G1.refreshObjects();
    G2.refreshObjects();
    G3.refreshObjects();

  }
}

package gravitationalmodel;

public class GravitationalObject 
{
  private double xPos;   //location and speed of gravitational object
  private double yPos;
  private double vX;
  private double vY;
  private double mass;


  public GravitationalObject(double x, double y, double xv, double yv, double m)
  {
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;
    vX = xv;
    vY = yv;
    mass = m;
  }

  public void refreshVectorField() // calculates gravitational field
  {
    int k = 1;
    for (int x = 0; x < 1920; ++x)
    {
      if (xPos > x)
        k = 1;
      else
        k= -1;
      if (xPos - x == 0)
        ++x;
      xArray[x] += k * (gravConst * mass) / Math.sqrt(xPos - x, 2.0); // errors on this line
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < 1200; ++y)
    {
      if (yPos < y)
        k = 1;
      else
        k= -1;
      yArray[y] += (gravConst * mass) / Math.sqrt(Math.abs(yPos - y), 2); //errors on this line
    }
  }

  public void refreshObjects()
  {
    vX += refreshRate/1000 * xArray[xPos]; // errors on these lines
    vY += refreshRate/1000 * yArray[yPos];
    xPos += refreshRate/1000 * vX;
    xPos += refreshRate/1000 * vX;
  }
}
```

Comment: "I am experiencing errors" is very vague. You need to give more details for this question.

Comment: Please tell us what errors is it and at which line is the error. I am sure your compiler tells you everything.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `GravitationalModel.xArray` from `GravitationalObject` without fully qualifying the static field. Either fully qualify the field, or create a method in `GravitationalModel` to do the work.

Note that public mutable fields are generally frowned upon in Java, because it breaks encapsulation. It's better to have your objects encapsulate data and behavior via methods, and keep the variables private.

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner, you should not hurry. Soon you would be able to write cool programs. There are lot of errors in this program and even program does not make any logic. You should practice some small programs first to get basics. Like you created following objects which you are not using at all.

```
GravitationalObject G1 = new GravitationalObject(500, 500, 10, 10, 10); // creates 3 interstellar objects taking x position,
GravitationalObject G2 = new GravitationalObject(400, 400, 10, 10, 10); // y position, x veleocity component, y velocity component
GravitationalObject G3 = new GravitationalObject(600, 600, 10, 10, 10); // mass of the object
```

Now comes to errors in program.

If you want to access instance variables `gravConst` or `refreshRate` in other class, you need to create object of class and access them.
or you can create them static and import them to class like this

`import static gravitationalmodel.GravitationalModel.xArray;
import static gravitationalmodel.GravitationalModel.yArray;
import static gravitationalmodel.GravitationalModel.gravConst;
import static gravitationalmodel.GravitationalModel.refreshRate;`

`Math.sqrt(double)` does not take 2 arguments so I think you want to use `xArray[x] += k * (gravConst * mass) / Math.pow(xPos - x, 2.0);`

and cast double to int as index of array can only be integer as follows

`vX += refreshRate / 1000 * xArray[(int)xPos]; 
 vY += refreshRate / 1000 * yArray[(int)yPos];`

So your final program is below:

```
package gravitationalmodel;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GravitationalModel {
    private Object timer;
    private GravitationalObject G1;
    private GravitationalObject G2;
    private GravitationalObject G3;
    public static double[] xArray;
    public static double[] yArray;
    final static public double gravConst = 0.000000000067;
    final static public int refreshRate = 25;

    public GravitationalModel() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(refreshRate, (ActionListener) this); // refreshes
                                                                        // model
                                                                        // every
                                                                        // 25
                                                                        // milliseconds
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GravitationalObject G1 = new GravitationalObject(500, 500, 10, 10, 10); // creates
                                                                                // 3
                                                                                // interstellar
                                                                                // objects
                                                                                // taking
                                                                                // x
                                                                                // position,
        GravitationalObject G2 = new GravitationalObject(400, 400, 10, 10, 10); // y
                                                                                // position,
                                                                                // x
                                                                                // veleocity
                                                                                // component,
                                                                                // y
                                                                                // velocity
                                                                                // component
        GravitationalObject G3 = new GravitationalObject(600, 600, 10, 10, 10); // mass
                                                                                // of
                                                                                // the
                                                                                // object

        xArray = new double[1920]; // assigns all elements of array to 0
        for (int x = 0; x < 1920; ++x) {
            xArray[x] = 0;
            // System.out.println(xArray[x]);
        }

        yArray = new double[1200];
        for (int x = 0; x < 1200; ++x) {
            yArray[x] = 0;
            // System.out.println(yArray[x]);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) // refreshes model
    {
        G1.refreshVectorField();
        G2.refreshVectorField();
        G3.refreshVectorField();
        G1.refreshObjects();
        G2.refreshObjects();
        G3.refreshObjects();

    }

}
```

and second class as

```
package gravitationalmodel;

import static gravitationalmodel.GravitationalModel.xArray;
import static gravitationalmodel.GravitationalModel.yArray;
import static gravitationalmodel.GravitationalModel.gravConst;
import static gravitationalmodel.GravitationalModel.refreshRate;

public class GravitationalObject {
    private double xPos; // location and speed of gravitational object
    private double yPos;
    private double vX;
    private double vY;
    private double mass;

    public GravitationalObject(double x, double y, double xv, double yv,
            double m) {
        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;
        vX = xv;
        vY = yv;
        mass = m;
    }

    public void refreshVectorField() // calculates gravitational field
    {
        int k = 1;
        for (int x = 0; x < 1920; ++x) {
            if (xPos > x)
                k = 1;
            else
                k = -1;
            if (xPos - x == 0)
                ++x;
            xArray[x] += k * (gravConst * mass) / Math.pow(xPos - x, 2.0); // errors
                                                                            // on
                                                                            // this
                                                                            // line
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < 1200; ++y) {
            if (yPos < y)
                k = 1;
            else
                k = -1;
            yArray[y] += (gravConst * mass) / Math.pow(Math.abs(yPos - y), 2); // errors
                                                                                // on
                                                                                // this
                                                                                // line
        }
    }

    public void refreshObjects() {
        vX += refreshRate / 1000 * xArray[(int)xPos]; // errors on these lines
        vY += refreshRate / 1000 * yArray[(int)yPos];
        xPos += refreshRate / 1000 * vX;
        xPos += refreshRate / 1000 * vX;
    }
}
```